# Can I give an emulator more disk space?

Tags: .net-3.5, compact-framework, emulation, windows-ce, handheld

The compilation of my Compact Framework app (.NET 3.5, VS 2008) failed with this error:

*Deployment and/or registration failed with error: 0x8973190e. Error writing file '%csidl_program_files%\hhs\system.data.dll'. Error 0x80070070: There is not enough space on the disk.*

Selecting Tools > Device Emulator Manager shows me nothing promising; nor does Project > Properties > Devices.

### UPDATE

Vasiliy, is this what you meant? I:

0) Created a folder on my C drive named "VirtualStorageCardForNewHHSCFVS2008"

1) In Project > Properties > Devices > Output file folder, I changed the settings from this:

[image]

...to this:

[image]

...but now I get different err msgs. If I simply shut down the emulator as soon as it pops up, I get, "The RPC server is unavailable"

Thereafter, on attempting to run it, I get, "Deployment and/or registration failed with error: 0x8973190e. Error writing file '\Windows\NETCFv35.ppc.armv4.cab'. Error 0x80070070: There is not enough space on the disk.
    Device Connectivity Component"

### UPDATE 2

I don't see a "Compress" option in my Project Properties; in fact, the whole collection of members are radically different:

[image]

Comment: Stop trying to use full framework assemblies in a CF app.  You're running out of space because Studio is trying to push the entire full .NET Framework to the device and it won't fit.  Even if you got it to download, it won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all the extra applications off of your Emulator.

It should have NOTHING on it but the essentials. Bare bones, if you like.

So, how do your DLL files get copied over to your device?

Simple! That happens when you start your debugger because your Project will be set to deploy everything it needs and it can compress the files (the compression helps, but it may not be necessary when starting the debugger).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My Project Properties members differ greatly from yours; see Update 2, if you're so inclined.

Comment: Oh, I see our properties are apparently from a Cab folder; I have no such folder...

Answer (score 1):

You can use StorageCard to deploy you application. The storage card on emulator is any folder on the host machine.

To select the StorageCard directory go to Emulator properties.

Comment: By "Emulator Properties" do you mean Project > Properties > Devices > Output file folder?

Comment: No. I mean the properties window from main menu in emulator window. Don't remember exacly the name. Something like File->Properties

Answer (score 1):

The error message may be misleading.
It says that you're lacking disk space but what you may actually be lacking is RAM in the emulator.
Windows CE implements a RAM-based file system named Object Store and if you didn't change the deployment locations of your app it will be deployed in RAM. You can add RAM to the emulator image, change your deployment location or change the percentage of RAM reserved for the object store in the system applet inside control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Actually my problem was a corrupted installation of the Compact Framework 3.5 in the dev machine. I re-installed it and no more "not enough space on disk" misleading error. http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=65