# Can I use a regular System.dll in a Compact Framework project?

Tags: dll, compact-framework, json.net, windows-ce, versioning

In my test Winforms app (in which I'm targeting .NET 3.5, to simulate the Windows CE / Compact Framework 3.5 app that this is a first-line test for as much as possible), I added some JSON.NET code to deserialize json returned from WebAPI methods:

```
try
{
    const string uri = "http://localhost:48614/api/departments";
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Content from HttpWebRequest is {0}", s));
        var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
        int i = 1;
        foreach (JObject obj in arr)
        {
            var id = (string)obj["Id"];
            var accountId = (double)obj["AccountId"];
            var departmentName = (string)obj["DeptName"];
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Object {0} in JSON array: id == {1}, accountId == {2}, deptName == {3}", i, id, accountId, departmentName));
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

...This runs fine in the .NET 3.5 Winforms app, but when I copied it over to the Windows CE-targetted app, the code wouldn't run, with the following errors spilling forth:

```
The type 'System.ComponentModel.IBindingList' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

The type 'System.ComponentModel.ITypedList' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0...

The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced....

The type 'System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor' is defined in an assembly...

The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged' ...

The type 'System.Uri'...
```

I saw that in the Winforms (testbed) app, I'm using version 2.0.0.0 of the "regular" (or "deluxe" when compared to CF) System.dll. In the Windows CE app, though, I was using the CF flavor of version 3.5 found here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.dll

I tried using version 2 CF from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\System.dll, but that failed, too - so it's apparently not really the *version* (3.5 vs. 2.0), but the "flavor" (CF vs "deluxe"/regular System.dll).

SO...I replaced the CF-flavored System.dll[s] with the one successfully used by the Winforms test app, explicitly the one in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll (I have no System.dll in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5, anyway).

It no longer gives those same err msgs as listed above, but there is another compile error that may (or may not be) related ([Can I give an emulator more disk space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415366/can-i-give-an-emulator-more-disk-space)) now.

Whether it is or not (related), it brings up the intriguing question: Will using a regular System.dll in a Windows CE project cause a problem?

If it will -- or there's a good chance that it will -- cause a problem, since it was apparently the JSON.NET code that required the change to an "off-colored" version of System.dll, is there a CF-ready / CF-specific version of JSON.NET? Will I have to create my own CF-targeted version of an assembly from the JSON.NET source?

### UPDATE

In the JSON.NET readme, it states:

*For a Compact Framework 3.5 build download Json.NET 3.5.*

Which I assumed meant the .DLL in \Json50r7\Bin\Net35

Am I wrong about that?

### UPDATE 2

When I attempt to open Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.sln in Windows 2008, with the intention of creating a CE-targeted assembly, it doesn't allow me, saying, "*The selected file is a solution file*, but was created by a newer version of this appllication and cannot be opened*"

It also says in the JSON.NET read me:

*Microsoft stopped support for the Compact Framework in Visual Studio 2010.*

...so I don't think I can open it in a newer version of VS2008 and create a CF-friendly DLL, either...

### UPDATE 3

Looking for a "Compact" folder in the download from http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113546, but I see no such folder:

[image]

It's not the "Portable" folder, is it?

Comment: Do you want a solution to the specific problem you've posed in the body of your question, or a more general response to the title of your question?

Comment: Either/or, but a solution would be preferable.

Comment: Pick one, and make the title match the body.  Titles appear in Google Search Results, so you're not doing anyone any favors by mismatching them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert Harvey suggests, the tile and the actual question here don't match.  You probably should fix that.

The answer to the current title "Can I use a regular System.dll in a Compact Framework Project?" is absolutely, definitively *no*.  You cannot mix and match.  Full-framework assemblies cannot run under the Compact Framework.  There's no way to make them work.  Period.  Stop trying this.

The answer to "How do I use JSON.NET is a Compact Framework Project" is that you should go to the JSON.NET [project site](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) on GitHub and specifically look at [the last JSON.NET 3.5 release (it was Release 8)](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/3.5.8) and download it.  Inside that zip file is a folder named "Compact" that contains an assembly named `Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll`.  Add a reference to that DLL to your Compact Framework 3.5 project.

Comment: I just downloaded version 8, but it has no Compact folder - see my Update 3 for what is there.

Comment: Not version 5.0 R8.  Version **3.5** Release 8.  Use the link in my answer.  You'll find the Compact folder as a subfolder in the Bin folder.